# Img src as a php variable

Tags: php, html, variables, image, src

What Im trying to do is write a script that grabs the url of thumbnails attached to posts in wordpress.  It sounds really easy(as I'm sure the solution is) but I can't seem to get it to work, I keep getting syntax errors no matter what I try.  The problem line is the second echo(Img src...).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'archive-thumb');
$image_url = $image_url[0];

    echo "<li class=\"recent-img-widget-li\"><a href='".get_permalink()."'>;
    echo "<img src=\"".$image_url."\" width=\"120\" height=\"120\">";
    echo "</a></li>";
```

Comment: If you start the echoed string with ' instead of " you don't need to escape the " in the html, like this: echo '<li class="recent-img-widget-li"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">';

Comment: And if the tornado of identical responses below doesn't fix the issue, you should try var_dump on wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'archive-thumb');
 to make sure you're even getting a url

Answer (score 4):

Simply enough, you're not closing your first string after `get_permalink()`. Yo need another quote after the `>`.

Comment: I'm plussing everyone in here so none of us feel sad when he chooses someone else to credit for this question.

Answer (score 3):

You never close the first string.  You just need a quote before the greater than on the first line (and possibly the second?).  Look at the syntax highlighting that SO has.

Answer (score 3):

A general guideline is to always look at the row above the one that is giving the error.

In this case you have forgotten to end the string in the last part of the first echo statement.

```
...ermalink()."'>;
```

Should be

```
...ermalink()."'>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I knew it was something small, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

For one you should close that first echo. Missing the closing "